# View main content and sidebar in one row. float:right not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to view the main content and a sidebar side-by-side in one row.
Pretty easy, I thought, just add a float:right; but it turned out not to work this easy.

You can find a prepared `jsfiddle` here: http://jsfiddle.net/W3MKx/

The sidebar (the thing with the input box) should constantly be 200px wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use floatting method, aside should be first in the flow:
http://jsfiddle.net/W3MKx/1/

```
<div id="all">
    <aside id="ball">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="ueoa" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search user" />
            <ul id="caoeu"></ul>
        </form>
    </aside>
    <article id="chat">
        <div id="chat-header"> <span class='label'>Site</span>
 <span id="iiae"></span>

            <button class="btn" id="nht">
                <img src="img/icon/htino.png" />View</button>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-entries"></div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the following: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3MKx/3/))

**Without changing your HTML structure** apply the following CSS:

```
#all {
    background: blue;
    overflow:hidden; /* This is mandatory to make the parent wrap around the children   */
}

#ball {
    background: red;
    float: right; /* float sidebar to the right */
    width:200px; /* constant width as you requested */
}

#chat{
    width:calc(100% - 210px); /* You can set the width in any way you choose - just make sure to leave room for the sidebar */
    float:left; /* float the chat to the left */
}
```

When working with floated elements it's probably best to set `overflow:hidden;` to the container - This will force it to wrap around all children regardless of their heights. You will also have to set the width of the chat so there's room for the sidebar. float the chat to the left and the sidebar to the right.